# Center image horizontally inside .docx generated with docx4j

Tags: java, html, css, image, docx4j

I've been trying for some days to center an image horizontally inside a *.docx* file generated from *HTML* with *docx4j* without success. What I've tried so far (and works in *HTML*) is:

```
<div align="center"><img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ..."></div>
```

(by centering outer div)

```
<div><img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ..." clase="img-default"></div>
```

with the following commands inside Style tag:

```
.img-default {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The code I'm using to generate the *.docx* is available [here](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInXHTMLFragment.java), guided from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971528/generate-docx-from-html-with-base64-images-with-docx4j). Thanks!

Comment: I think `div` tags are just rendered as paragraphs when you import them aren't they? So I wouldn't be sure that all style attributes would be honoured (e.g. centering a container).

Comment: @Ben leaving the images alone without a 'div' inside them didn't change anything... Tried putting them right inside the 'body' tag, and still no centered...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm saying I'm not aware of any code which will take a div centred by CSS, and ensure it remains centred when parsed into an OpenXML paragraph entity. You may need to post-process the generated paragraph/ inline image in docx4j to ensure it's centred in the docx file.

Comment: I was thinking I may do so... Do you know how could I post-process it? I guess it would have something to do with an id set to it... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing with code at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML (I didn't try v3.2.1), the following works for me:

```
    String xhtml= "<div align=\"center\">" +
                "<img src='" + PNG_IMAGE_DATA + "'  />" +
            "</div>";
```

or

```
    String xhtml= "<div align=\"center\">" +
                "<p><img src='" + PNG_IMAGE_DATA + "'  /></p>" +
            "</div>";
```

I didn't try putting the align attribute on the image itself.

I note [Center image using text-align center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center) but haven't tried:

```
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Getting that to work might well require a code patch.

Comment: Genius! First choice didn't work (that was what I was doing), but the second one (the one using P) worked like a charm! Thanks pal!